# Sending data to a controller with AJAX POST

Tags: ajax

I am using AJAX to send request to controller, but the data is sent with the GET method. I want the request send with the POST method.

The following is the code I used.

```
var table_url = '/table-data'+params;
var elementSettings = {};
elementSettings.url = table_url;
elementSettings.progress = {
  type: 'throbber'
};
Drupal.ajax(elementSettings).execute();
```

Comment: Did you try to send the params via elementSettings.submit?

Comment: The [default appears to be POST](https://i.imgur.com/SlrZaMs.png) you sure its using GET?

Comment: @NoSssweat Yes I am sure Its using GET

Comment: @NoSssweat is right, POST is default. asdsadsaadasdsa, are you aware that POST requests can also send GET parameters?

Comment: @4k4 No I am not aware about this. When I send a request with which contain around 1700 values like var param =&agr="ayx abc anc | anchd hdbdbc hdhd | cbcbc ccc cccc ccc cc cc cbcccnc| value 4....  | value 1700"  and i am getting an error i.e Error: URI Too Long

Comment: OK, this is then as I had suspected in my first comment. Add the parameters to `elementSettings.submit` and not to the URL. This will then be transferred to the `data` parameter of the lower level $.ajax you see in @NoSssweat answer.

Comment: @4k4 could you please look on the screenshot - https://prnt.sc/up7bgr. Request Url showing  all send parameter's value even showing Request Method : POST

Comment: Yes, the screenshot confirms what I've tried to clarify. I'm not sure what is still unclear to you?

Comment: Yes got is : elementSettings.url = table_url;
elementSettings.progress = {
  type: 'throbber'
};
Drupal.ajax(elementSettings).execute(); Drupal consider this as a url rather a var param is a paramter. Is there any way that I can pass var param as paramter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to send POST parameters add them to `elementSettings.submit`:

```
elementSettings.submit = {
  foo: 'bar'
};
```

and remove the GET parameters from `elementSettings.url`.

Answer (score 1):

You could always non-Drupaly do it like this

```
$("#some-id").click(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/table-data'+params',
    data: JSON.stringify ({username: 'No Sssweat'}),
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function(){
      $(this).prepend('<span class="ajax-progress-throbber"><div class="throbber">&nbsp;&nbsp;</div></span>');
    },
    success: function(data) { 
      alert(data); 
    },
    complete: function(){
     $('.ajax-progress-throbber').remove();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I want to use  drupal ajax function because pagination seem running with drupal ajax